# light confirm script

Tags: javascript

http://lalalafactory.blogspot.com/2008/02/light-alet-lightalertjs.html

Can anyone tell me what to change that JS confirm button will also work. I add

```
function confirm(obj){
    new LightAlert(obj);
}
```

but still works like alert not confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, you would have to get in and modify their code. You can use the [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) and acheive this.